# Within cluster sum of square of the next iteration is bigger than the previous when K-means is applied to SURF features?

Tags: k-means, sift

I am using K-Means algorithm to classify `SIFT` vector features.

My `K-Means` skeleton is

```
     choose first K points of the data as initial centers

     do{

         // assign each point to the corresponding cluster
         data assignment;

         // get the recalculated center of each cluster
         // suppose point is multi-dimensional data, e.g.(x1, x2, x3...)
         // the center is composed by average value of each dimension.
         // e.g. ((x1 + y1 + ...)/n, (x2 + y2 + ...)/n ...)
         new centroid;

         sum total memberShipChanged;

     }while(some point still changes their membership, i.e. total memberShipChanged != 0)
```

We all know that K-Means aims to get the minimal of `within cluster sum of square`, illustrated as below snapshot.

[image]

And we can use a `do while` iteration to reach the target. Now I prove why after every iteration the `within cluster sum of square` is smaller.

Proof:

For simplicity, I only consider 2 iterations.

After *data assignment process*, every descriptor vector has its new nearest cluster center, so the `within cluster sum of square` decrease after this process. After all, the `within cluster of square` is sum of every vector to one center, if every vector choose it own new   nearest neighbor, there is no doubt that the sum decreases.

In *new centroid process*, I use arithmetic mean to calculate the new center vector, the local sum of one cluster must decrease.

So the `within cluster sum of square` decrease twice in one iteration. And after several iterations, every descriptor vector doesn't change its membership, and `within cluster sum of square` reaches the local minimum.

===============================================================================

Now My question comes:

my SURF data is derived from 3000 images, every descriptor vector is 128-dimension, and there are 1,296,672 vectors in total. And in my code, I print

1)vector number of each clsuter

2)total memeberShipChanged in one iteration

3)within cluster sum of square before one iteration.

Here is output:

sum of square : **8246977014860**

90504 228516 429755 266828 1653711 398631 193081 240072

memberShipChanged : **3501098**

sum of square : **4462579627000**

244521 284626 448700 228211 1361902 303864 317464 311810

memberShipChanged : **975442**

sum of square : **4561378972772**

323746 457785 388988 228431 993328 304606 473668 330546

memberShipChanged : **828709**

sum of square : **4678353976030**

359537 480818 346767 222646 789858 332876 612672 355924

memberShipChanged : **563256**

......

I only list 4 iteration output of it. From the output, we can see that after first iteration. `within cluster sum of square` really decrease from 8246977014860 to 4462579627000. But other iterations are nearly of on use in minimize it, but we can still observe the memberShipChanged is converging. I don't know why this happen. I think the first k-means iteration is overwhelming important.

Besides, what should I set the new center coordinate of a empty cluster when the memberShipChanged still doesn't converge to 0 yet? Now I use (0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...). But is this accurate, perhaps the `within cluster of sum` increases due to it.

Comment: I assume you've implemented K-Means on your own? If so, have you confirmed that your implementation works on simple synthetic data sets?